# statistics random sample question

Tags: statistics

Pizza Hut restaurants want to switch to using new cheese. Assuming that 80% of the population cannot tell the taste difference between the new cheese and the currently used cheese, what's the approximate probability that in a random sample of 100 individuals, at least 29 can taste the difference between the two types of cheeses?

```
A) 1 - Φ(0.33)
B) 1 - Φ(-0.92)
C) 1 - Φ(40)
D) 1 - Φ(2.12)
E) none of the above
```

Could not figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Google "binomial distribution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

telling the truth...the correct answer should be

D1)

$$1-\Phi(2.125)$$

but I figure they want you to say D)